# Is there a PHP Fleiss' Kappa implementation?

Tags: php, statistics, classification

I'm looking for a PHP implementation of [Fleiss' Kappa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleiss%27_kappa) that is publicly available. So far, I found some classes written in [Java, Perl, Ruby and Python](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Statistics/Fleiss%27_kappa), but nothing in PHP.

Do you have any idea or suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: My guess would be that your time would probably be spent writing one yourself than continuing to search. With all the existing implementations you referenced, it shouldn't take long.

Answer (score 0):

Because I needed it too, I wrote this function:

```
function fleissKappa($table){

    /*
    *   author Tom Aizenberg
    *   
    *   $table is an n x m array containing the classification counts
    *   
    *   adapted from the example in en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fleiss'_kappa 
    * 
    */

    $subjects = count($table);
    $classes = count($table[0]);
    $raters = array_sum($table[0]);

    for($q = 1; $q < count($table); $q++){

        if(count($table[$q])!=$classes){

            print("no equal number of classes.");
            exit(0);
        }

        if(array_sum($table[$q])!=$raters){

            print("no equal number of raters.");
            exit(0);
        }

    }

    $pj = array();
    $pi = array();

    for($j = 0; $j < $subjects; $j++){

        $pi[$j] =0;
    }

    for($i = 0; $i < $classes; $i++){

        $tpj = 0;

        for($j = 0; $j < $subjects; $j++){

            $tpj += $table[$j][$i];
            $pi[$j] +=  $table[$j][$i]*$table[$j][$i];

        }

        $pj[$i] = $tpj/($raters*$subjects);

    }

    for($j = 0; $j < $subjects; $j++){
        $pi[$j] = $pi[$j]-$raters;
        $pi[$j] = $pi[$j]*(1/($raters*($raters-1)));
    }

    $pcarret = array_sum($pi)/$subjects;
    $pecarret = 0;

    for($i = 0; $i < count($pj);$i++){

        $pecarret += $pj[$i]*$pj[$i];

    }

    $kappa = ($pcarret-$pecarret)/(1-$pecarret);

    return $kappa;

}
```

Test it:

```
$test = array(
        array(0,0,0,0,14),
        array(0,2,6,4,2),
        array(0,0,3,5,6),
        array(0,3,9,2,0),
        array(2,2,8,1,1),
        array(7,7,0,0,0),
        array(3,2,6,3,0),
        array(2,5,3,2,2),
        array(6,5,2,1,0),
        array(0,2,2,3,7));

print(fleissKappa($test));
```